# I have to change my number last digit and first digit but without using functions only with integers or loops. For example from 12345 to 52341

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
// Here I seperate my number because at first I have to seperate and then I have to change the first digit and last digit.
    int numri, shifrat, i = 0, a, shuma = 0, m, d;
    cout << "Jep nje numer \n";
    cin >> numri;
    m = numri;
    while (numri != 0) {
        i++;
        numri = numri / 10;     
    }
    d = pow(10, i - 1);
    numri = m; 
    while (numri != 0) {
        shifrat = numri / d;
        cout << shifrat << "  ";
        numri = numri % d;
        d = d / 10;
    }

//Now after that I have to change the last digit and first digit. Please help me.
//But I'm not allowed to use functions or swap only integers and loops or conditions.

    cin.get();
}
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: do you know how to do it on paper? If you have a number with digits `xy` and a digit `z`, what maths operations do you need to get the number `xyz` ?

Comment: That's what I need to know. Can you explain me?

Comment: @Hana What happens if the number created has a value greater than the maximum integer?  For example 1000123039 and thus the number is 9000123031?  The result will not fit in a 32-bit integer.  Whoever assigned this to you didn't consider overflow?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To exchange first and last digit in a number ABCDEF --> FBCDEA

num = 12345
res = 52341

the idea is that :

52341 = 12345 - 10005 + 50001

first digit fd = num % 10

decimal places multiplier df = 1

```
until num is not zero we do
last digit ld = num
num = num / 10
if num != 0 decimal places multiplier df = df*10
```

result = ABCDEF - F - A*100000 + A + F*100000

```
int m = numri;
int ld = 0; // last digit(most)
int fd = numri % 10; // first digit(least)
int df = 1; // last digit multiplier 10^n where n is decimal places
while (numri != 0) {
    ld = numri;// this will be the last digit in last iteration
    numri = numri / 10;
    if(numri) df = df * 10;
}
int res = m - fd - ld * df + fd * df + ld;
cout<<res;
```

example:

```
if the num = 12345

fd = 12345 % 10 =5
df = 1

num = 12345 / 10 = 1234
df = df*10 = 10

num = 1234 / 10 = 123
df = df*10 = 100

num = 123 / 10 = 12
df = df*10 = 1000

fd = num = 12
num = 12 / 10 = 1
df = df*10 = 10000

fd = num = 1
num = 1/10 =0
df not changed
loop exit

result = 12345 - 5  - 1*10000 + 1 + 5*10000 = 62341
```

Comment: Where I have to write this at the end?

Comment: Please add some context and explain what this code does. Just giving OP some code to copy and paste will not help much especially if this is some assingment. And even more so if OP is really new to c++.

Comment: This code just seperates the digits for example 12345 to 1 2 3 4 5. Now I have to change the last digit with the first digit.

Comment: The res is not working it shows the same number without changing anything.

Comment: Actually no, can you explain me please

Comment: @Hana check it now

Answer (score 2):

It is more about maths than anything else.

To get the last digit of an integer we can use modulo:

```
z = abc....xyz % 10
```

To "remove" that digit from the number we use

```
abc...xy =  abc...xyz / 10
```

(where `/` denotes integer division, ie `34/10 == 3`).

I think this is what you already know how to do. Instead of deep diving into code, you should have done the maths also for the missing part first.

To add a digit to an integer we do

```
abc...xyz = (abc...xy * 10) + z
```

Only now you have all pieces necessary to start writing code:

```
int main() {
    int inp;
    int outp = 0;
    std::cin >> inp;      // read_input
    while(inp > 0) {      // reverse
         int digit = ...  // get_digit
         inp = ...        // remove_digit
         outp = ...       // add_digit
    }
    std::cout << outp;
}
```

It is unfortunate that you are not allowed to use functions. One of the next lessons should be that functions are much better than comments in naming things and making your code explicit

```
int read_input();
int remove_digit(int x); 
int add_digit(int x,int digit);
int reverse(int x);

int main() {
    int inp = read_input();
    std::cout << reverse(inp);
}
```

Comment: Yes but I can't use functions

Comment: @Hana sorry I missed the "without functions" in your title, edited the answer

Answer (score 1):

The program can be written without using the function `pow`.

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ";

        unsigned int n;

        if ( not ( std::cin >> n ) or n == 0 ) break;

        std::cout << '\n';

        const unsigned int Base = 10;

        unsigned int factor = 1;

        while ( not ( n / factor < Base ) ) factor *= Base;

        unsigned int last_digit = n / factor;
        unsigned int first_digit = n % Base;

        n %= factor;

        n = n - first_digit + last_digit;

        first_digit *= factor;

        n = first_digit + n;

        std::cout << n << "\n\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 987654321

187654329

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 12345

52341

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 100

1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

1

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

If these statements

```
if ( not ( std::cin >> n ) or n == 0 ) break;
```

and

```
while ( not ( n / factor < Base ) ) factor *= Base;
```

contain symbols that you do not know yet then you can rewrite them like

```
if ( !( std::cin >> n ) || n == 0 ) break;
```

and

```
while ( !( n / factor < Base ) ) factor *= Base;
```

Comment: How can I write it without using not :

Comment: if ( not ( std::cin >> n ) or n == 0 ) break;
This

Comment: @Hana Why do you not like "not"?:) You can rewrite it like if ( ! ( std::cin >> n ) || n == 0 ) break; And this while ( not ( n / factor < Base ) ) factor *= Base; like while ( !( n / factor < Base ) ) factor *= Base; That is "not" is the same as the exclamation sign "!".

Comment: Because I'm not allowed to.

Comment: @Hana Why are you not allowed?! Who said this?

Comment: `not` is not a function, it's just an alias for `!`. @VladfromMoscow `not ( n / factor < Base )` makes it look like a function call, I guess ;)

Comment: Can you please explain me how did you do this . I mean the arithmetic

Comment: @Hana To find the first digit is simple. first_digit = n % Base. For the last digit we should multiply the factor until the result is less than 10. For example if you have number 12 then 12 / 1 gives 12. So you have to multiply the factor by 10. Now 12 / 10 gives 1 and it is the last digit in the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a program with 4 variables - n, the given number, cn - the created number, u - the last digit of the given number and p - the 10^p number; 
   You will save the last n digit and create the 10^p number in while. Then, using the formula

```
   cn = ((u * p + cn % p) /10) * 10 + n;
```

you will create the new number;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int n, cn, u, p;

cin>>n;

u = n % 10;
cn = n;
p = 1;

while(n>9) {
p = p * 10;
n = n / 10;
}

cn = ((u * p + cn % p) /10) * 10 + n;

cout<<cn;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution can cause overflow.  See my comment in the main section.

Comment: He specified only with Integers.

Comment: See my comment above in the main section again, along with the example -- the input fits in a 32-bit int, but the output will not.  It uses only integers, but will produce an overflow.  This should have been obvious, but I guess not.